# Dynamic delay value with repeatWhen()

Tags: rx-java

Right now I'm implementing some polling logic with RxJava.  I'm supposed to poll an endpoint a number of times until it tells me to stop.  Additionally, each response comes back with a time that I'm supposed to delay by before polling again.  My logic looks something like this right now:

```
service.pollEndpoint()
    .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .takeUntil(Blah::shouldStopPolling);
```

Right now I have the delay value hardcoded to 5000, but I'd like it to depend on a value in the poll response.  I tried using a flatmap that returned `Observable.just(pollResponse).repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(pollResponse.getDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))`, but that didn't seem like the right idea since it messed with the source Observable.  I feel like it's something simple that I'm overlooking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As @JohnWowUs mentioned, you need out-of-band communication, but if you subscribe to the sequence more than once, you can use `defer` to have per-subscriber state:

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
    int[] pollDelay = { 0 };
    return service.pollEndpoint()
    .doOnNext(response -> pollDelay[0] = response.getDelay())
    .repeatWhen(o -> o.flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(pollDelay[0], MILLISECONDS)))
    .takeUntil(Blah::shouldStopPolling);
});
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the solution I posted? Using recursion there's no need for out-of-band communication, but I'm not sure if this introduced any problems that I missed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the side effect operator doOnNext to update a delay variable and then use that in your repeatWhen

```
int pollDelay = 5000;

service.pollEndpoint()
.doOnNext(pollResponse -> pollDelay=pollResponse.getDelay())
.repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(pollDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
.takeUntil(Blah::shouldStopPolling);
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like there to not be any side effects. :/

Comment: The only way I can see that being done is to write your own repeat style operator.

Comment: This won't work, as `repeatWhen` will only evaluate once, so the delay won't change even if you change your `pollDelay`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
public static Observable<PollResponse> createPollObservable(RetrofitService service, PollResponse response) {
    return Blah::shouldStopPolling(response)
        ? Observable.empty()
        : service
            .pollEndpoint()
            .delaySubscription(getPollDelay(response), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .concatMap(response1 -> createPollObservable(service, response1)
                    .startWith(response1)
                    .takeUntil(Blah::shouldStopPolling)
            );
}
```

It instead uses recursion to always have the latest PollResponse object and also switches to `delaySubscription()` rather than `repeatWhen()`.

Comment: @akarnokd This is the solution I'm using right now and it seems to work fine without any out-of-band communication.  Does it look OK?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* abuse `retryWhen` - but I'm just saying it is possible, not that you *should* do it:

```
package com.example.retrywhen;

import com.example.LoggingAction1;

import org.pcollections.PVector;
import org.pcollections.TreePVector;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.functions.Func0;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

import static com.example.Utils.sleep;

public class RetryWhenDynamicDelayTest {

    final static PVector<Integer> delays = TreePVector.<Integer>singleton(500).plus(1_000).plus(2_000);

    final static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    final static Observable<Integer> willCycleThroughTheList = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call() {
            return Observable.just(delays.get(count.getAndIncrement() % 3));
        }
    });

    static class ThisIsNotReallyAnException extends Throwable {
        final Integer integer;

        ThisIsNotReallyAnException(Integer integer) {
            this.integer = integer;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        willCycleThroughTheList.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Integer integer) {
                return Observable.error(new ThisIsNotReallyAnException(integer));
            }
        })
                .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        System.out.println("Millis since start: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
                    }
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Integer> call(Throwable throwable) {
                        if (throwable instanceof ThisIsNotReallyAnException) {
                            ThisIsNotReallyAnException thisIsNotReallyAnException = (ThisIsNotReallyAnException) throwable;
                            return Observable.just((thisIsNotReallyAnException.integer)).concatWith(Observable.error(throwable));
                        } else {
                            return Observable.error(throwable);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
                        return observable.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                                if (throwable instanceof ThisIsNotReallyAnException) {
                                    ThisIsNotReallyAnException thisIsNotReallyAnException = (ThisIsNotReallyAnException) throwable;
                                    return Observable.timer(thisIsNotReallyAnException.integer, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                } else {
                                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new LoggingAction1<Object>(""));

        sleep(10_000);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Millis since start: 75
call (): 500
Millis since start: 590
call (): 1000
Millis since start: 1591
call (): 2000
Millis since start: 3593
call (): 500
Millis since start: 4094
call (): 1000
Millis since start: 5095
call (): 2000
Millis since start: 7096
call (): 500
Millis since start: 7597
call (): 1000
Millis since start: 8598
call (): 2000
```

Answer (score -2):

```
service.endpoint()
 .flatMap((Function<Response<Void>, SingleSource<?>>) response -> Single.just(response).delaySubscription(getDelayFromResponce(response), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .repeat()
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Can you share some explanation about that code? Why do you think it solves the question, and which are the crucial parts?

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.