# repeating RxJava pipeline with multicasting

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava and cannot figure out how to implement repeatable polling with a ConnectableObservable, with 2 subscribers processing the events on different threads.

I have a pipeline that roughly looks like this:

[image]

I would like to repeat the whole pipeline after a delay in a similar fashion to the solution from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/448

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> pollValue())
.repeatWhen(o -> o.concatMap(v -> Observable.timer(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
```

or [Dynamic delay value with repeatWhen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927550/dynamic-delay-value-with-repeatwhen).

This works fine with a plain (non-connectable) Observable, but not with multicasting.

Code example:

Works

```
    final int[] i = {0};
    Observable<Integer> integerObservable =
            Observable.defer(() -> Observable.fromArray(i[0]++, i[0]++, i[0]++));

    integerObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(","))
            .map(StringBuilder::toString)
            .toObservable().repeatWhen(o -> o.concatMap(v -> Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Does not work:

```
    final int[] i = {0};
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> integerObservable =
            Observable.defer(() -> Observable.fromArray(i[0]++, i[0]++, i[0]++))
            .publish();

    integerObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(System.out::println);

    integerObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(","))
            .map(StringBuilder::toString)
            .toObservable().repeatWhen(o -> o.concatMap(v -> Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    integerObservable.connect();
```

Comment: im not clear you want to subscribe an emitter with 2 subscriber in different thread process the item and than what do you want to do with item ?

Comment: It can be just printing the items out as in the code example, or offloading the items to a blocking queue where they will leave Rx Pipeline.

Once the emitter completes though, I want to repeat the pipeline from the start (do the next DB poll) after a variable delay. That is easy to do outside Rx, but I would like to keep it within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second example is not in the multicasting. It's in the collect operator and repeatWhen.

Consider repeatWhen like a 'hook' you are connecting to the onComplete method. This 'hook' will intercept the onComplete method and "override" it so it won't be called except for the first time that this observable has completed before starting the repeat process.

Without a onComplete method called the collect operator doesn't know how many items it should collect. So you would have to handle the logic of how to collect the items and where to store them outside of the stream but it would be a workaround.

This is an example for it:

```
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    final String[] currentString = {""};

    final int[] i = {0};
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> integerObservable =
            Observable.defer(() -> Observable.fromArray(i[0]++, i[0]++, i[0]++))
                    .doOnComplete(() -> {
                        test.add(currentString[0]);
                        currentString[0] = "";
                    })
                    .repeatWhen(o -> {
                        return o.concatMap(v ->
                                Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                                    test.add(currentString[0]);
                                    currentString[0] = "";
                                }));
                    })
                    .publish();

    integerObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    integerObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .map((sa) -> {
                currentString[0] = currentString[0] + sa;
                System.out.println(currentString[0]);
                return sa;
            })
            .subscribe();
```

In this example we use the onComplete method of the observable we hold the timer to reset our state. This example doesn't take in consideration the option when the consumers are slower to consume dhe data than the delay for the repeat(it will result in a overflow of result from one chain of data to the other). I would suggest using other ways to handle the repeat part for example:

final int[] i = {0};

```
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> integerObservable =
            Observable.defer(() -> Observable.fromArray(i[0]++, i[0]++, i[0]++)).publish();

    Observable b = integerObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    Observable a = integerObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(","))
            .map(StringBuilder::toString)
            .toObservable();

    Observable
            .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnSubscribe((d) -> {
                a.subscribe(System.out::println);
                b.subscribe(System.out::println);

                integerObservable.connect();
            })
            .doOnNext((d) -> {
                a.subscribe(System.out::println);
                b.subscribe(System.out::println);

                integerObservable.connect();
            })
            .doOnComplete(() -> {})
            .subscribe();
```

The first connect it's for the first time of the execution and onNext is called every 1 second and it restarts the whole pipeline again from the beginning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the second example and it prints 
0 | 0,1,2, | 1 | 2
but does not repeat - I expect to see something like 0 | 0,1,2, | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3,4,5, | 5 | ...

Comment: Yep. They are executing in 2 different threads. So it might be even 0 1 0,1,2 2 or 0 1 2 0,1,2  because of they are executing in different threads and are basically 2 different chains. They have no effect on each other like for example wait for the first to finish then collect on the other one.

Comment: Sorry - the process exited before the next sequence (starting from 3) appeared. It works as expected.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear if this is what you are asking for but maybe this will help you

```
  Observable<Integer> integerObservable1;
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Integer[] integers = {1, 2, 3};
    Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.fromArray(integers);

    integerObservable1 = Observable.zip(integerObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), integerObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (integer, integer2) -> {
        System.out.println(integer + " " + integer2);
        return integer;
    })
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                integerObservable1.subscribe();
            });
    integerObservable1.subscribe();

}
```