# RXJAVA ,Kotlin : i need to repeat a task with dynamic delay like after 2 seconds,5 sec,3 sec etc

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to repeat the task for several delay in time i tried with repeatWhen also but it delays with the same time.here is the code i tried

```
Observable.just(1)
           .repeatWhen {
               it.delay(getAnswerIntervalTime(),TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           }
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .doOnNext {
               updateScore(it)
           }
          .takeUntil{
              it>60
          }
```

Pls give me the best solutions for this
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927550/dynamic-delay-value-with-repeatwhen check this

Comment: thanks that one worked